# In Excel, How to check whether two columns are duplicate or not?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two columns in an excel sheet, 
I want to check whether both columns are exactly same or not. Same I mean to say the sequence itself (Ax should be same as Bx).

For example,

A B

x1 x1

x2 x2

x3 x3

x4 y4

Here 4th column should be highlighted as x4 and y4 are not same.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Three options:

**Conditional Format**

If you just want to highlight differences, add a conditional format.

1. Highlight columns A and B
2. Add A conditional format highlight rule > more rules
3. Use a custom formula
4. =if($A1<>$B1,1,0)
5. Add a fill format to highlight your cells

**Formula**

If you want to know whether or not ANY cell in column A or B is different, you

1. Add the formula =if(not(A1=B1),1,0) to cell C1
2. copy this cell and paste to column C
3. Add the formula =if(sum(C:C)>0,'NOT EQUAL','EQUAL') to D1
4. D1 will now tell you whether column A = B

**MACRO**

Add a macro and do something with it. This macro will just paste result into cell E1 and display a message box when you run it.

```
Sub ColumnCheck()
Dim i, LastRow, LastRowA, LastRowB, response
'get last row in column A and B, rather than 
'iterating through all possible rows
LastRowA = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LastRowB = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'get the greatest row between A and B
If LastRowA >= LastRowB Then
    LastRow = LastRowA
Else
    LastRow = LastRowB
End If
'iterate through all rows comparing them.
For i = 1 To LastRow
    If Cells(i, "A").Value <> Cells(i, "B").Value Then
         response = "The columns are not equal!"
         Range("E1") = response
         MsgBox (response)
         Exit Sub
    End If
Next
response = "The columns are equal!"
Range("E1") = response
MsgBox (response)
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

You could also use an array formula to find the first row (if any) where the two cells don't match:-

```
=IFERROR("Difference in row "&MATCH(TRUE,A:A<>B:B,0),"No Difference")
```

(must be entered with  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>   <kbd>Shift</kbd>   <kbd>Enter</kbd>  )